# Multiresolution subdivision gets rid of smoothing

Tags: modifiers, sculpting, multiresolution

[image]

Above is what my retopo low poly mesh looks like with the multires modifier on it.
[image]

Above is what the underlying sculpt looks like. For some reason the multires modifier gets rid of the smooth shading and I can't turn it back on by clicking smooth shading.
[image]

Here is what the topology looks like. It does this flat kind of shading with the whole mesh not just the head. I'm just putting it near the head as an example.

[image]

When I put the multires close to 0, the smooth shading comes back.

Something is telling me that the shading is supposed to look like this because of some technical property of how the multiresolution modifier works but that doesn't make sense to me since smooth shading doesn't seem like a complex thing to implement here and I can't find any posts that confirm this. Even with that, in in2vert's details tutorial, his mesh still looks smooth after he subdivides with the multires modifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around with it for a week I found out that all I had to do was just use the smooth brush in sculpt mode to get rid of the hard edges. Another thing was that I forgot to apply the shrinkwrap modifier before sculpting the mesh again. Hope this helps someone out there in the future!